# Similar problem of Hadamard's maximal determinant problem

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Hadamard's maximal determinant problem asks for the largest determinant of a matrix with elements equal to 1 or −1.
But what would be the case when the elements are equal to $\pm1\text{ or }0$?

I've tried to look for some reference, but all the reference I found were about elements being equal to 0 or -1 at best.

Anyone knows something about the case for elements being equal to $\pm1\text{ or }0$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hardmath
Thank you for your comment. I've checked out the topics you've provided. 
Totally unimodular matrices is not the one what I'm looking for. I'm interested in the determinant of a matrix whose elements are equal to 0 or$\pm1$.
For the incidence matrices of directed graphs, it sounded quite interesting. I haven't checked it out fully, but I will surely take a look.

Comment: Closely related (limited to $3\times 3$ matrices): [Maximum and minimum of determinant of matrices with entries from {0,1} or {−1,0,1}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379091/maximum-and-minimum-of-determinant-of-matrices-with-entries-from-0-1-or)

Comment: A better search topic for you would be [conference matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_matrix).  See also [Determinants of matrices of conference type](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379596004120) and a related[discussion by P. Cameron](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/a-matrix-problem/)

Comment: According to a remark under [OEIS A003432](http://oeis.org/A003432), the maximal determinant attained by a ternary $\{-1,0,1\}$-entry matrix is the same as attained by binary $\{-1,1\}$-entry matrices (of size $n\times n$).  This seems plausible, but I've not seen how to prove it.  I'll post an Answer if I can figure that out.

Comment: @hardmath
Thank you for introducing many references. I will surely check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum (absolute) determinant of an $n\times n$ (real) matrices with entries in $\{0,\pm 1\}$ is the same as the maximum determinant when their entries are restricted to $\{\pm 1\}$.

This is noted without proof in the [OEIS A003432 sequence](http://oeis.org/A003432), "largest determinant of a (real) $\{0,1\}$-matrix of order $n$."

> Suppose `M = (m(i,j))` is an `n X n` matrix of real numbers. Let
> `a(n) = max det M` subject to `m(i,j) = 0 or 1` [this sequence],
> `g(n) = max det M` subject to `m(i,j) = -1 or 1` [A003433](https://oeis.org/A003433),
> `h(n) = max det M` subject to `m(i,j) = -1, 0 or 1` [A003433](https://oeis.org/A003433),
> `F(n) = max det M` subject to `0 <= m(i,j) <= 1` [this sequence],
> `G(n) = max det M` subject to `-1 <= m(i,j) <= 1` [A003433](https://oeis.org/A003433).
>
> Then a(n) = F(n), g(n) = h(n) = G(n), g(n) = 2^(n-1)*a(n-1). Thus all five problems are equivalent.

Apparently the proof is a simple matter of considering the cofactor expansion of the matrix determinant.  An article "The Hadamard Maximum Determinant Problem," by Joel Brenner (American Math Monthly Vol. 79, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1972), pp. 626-630) available online through [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317092) merely says this:

> Consider any real $n\times n$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ with $|a_{ij}|\le 1$. Expanding the determinant of any such $A$ by minors along successive rows it is apparent that $\det A$ is dominated by the determinant of a $(-1,1)$ matrix; i.e., a matrix all of whose entries are either $-1$ or $1$.  Since there are finitely many such matrices the maximum determinant problem has a solution for each $n$.

We could elaborate on this by asking for the $\{0,\pm 1\}$-matrix, among those attaining the maximum determinant, having *fewest* zero entries.  If there were a zero entry, then by the cofactor of that entry being either non-negative or non-positive, we could vary the entry from $0$ to either $1$ or $-1$ respectively to attain the maximum determinant with fewer zero entries.

Answer (score 2):

Actually Hadamard's determinant inequality is more general and also applies to your question. Thanks to @hardmath for pointing out the reference [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06756.pdf).

The determinant of any $n\times n$ complex matrix $A$ with columns $a_i$ obeys

$$
| \det(A) |\leq \prod_{1\leq i\leq n} \Vert a_i \Vert,
$$
where the norm is the Euclidean norm.

It happens that certain $\pm 1$ entry Hadamard matrices achieve this bound. If you introduce a single zero in such a matrix without making it singular, you can compare the resulting determinant to this upperbound.

Since the proof is via the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, and achieved for the case of equal norm columns, introducing this zero is unlikely to achieve the upperbound.

In your case of entries from $\{0,\pm 1\}$, the squareroot of the Hamming weight of each row would appear in the right hand side of the bound.

Comment: It is true that Hadamard's original result (1893), posed for square matrices with complex entries of magnitude at most one, applies to the subset of matrices asked about here.  This [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.06756.pdf) of the literature explains how that led to interest in determinants of $\pm 1$ entry matrices.